# tomcat datasource with hibernate and Timeout waiting for idle object exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, tomcat, datasource

I am using **Tomcat Data-source with hibernate**

```
<Resource 
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
maxActive="8" maxIdle="8" maxWait="10000"
username="*****"  
name="jdbc/sakila" password="*****"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila"/>
```

and in hibernate

```
<propertyname="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/sakila</property>
```

after implementing I am facing the following exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
```

this exception occur at night , when I am sleeping :) and as I go office at morning I found this exception. I think this is connection pooling exception that tomcat provide?

please update me !

This it is suitable to use tomcat Data-source with hibernate? or we should use C3P0 third party connection polling?;

currently, looking solution for tomcate data source

Comment: You allow only 8 simmultaneous connections to the database. This seems low for a web application. Also timing is suspicious. Do you have any background processes running in the middle of the night? Can you show a full stack trace?

Comment: @Olaf middle of the night only one process running again and again? at start we begin the transaction and at end we commit the transaction and for exception rollback the transaction:) `You allow only 8 simmultaneous connections to the database` does it not increase automatically?

Comment: Does it fail while running that nightly process? If so, does it fail the very first time it tries to get a connection inside that process? Does that process try to get a connection more than once?

Comment: Could you please provide the max thread count for the server connector as a comparison to the db max count?  Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The number of the connections in the pool grows automatically until it reaches maxActive.

Per Tomcat documentation, maxActive is:

The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time. The default value is 100

You severly restricted the maximum number of the simultaneous database connections to 8.

I would suggest to increase this number to at least 50. Then start monitoring the number of the connections in the pool. If the number of the connections steadily grows, whitout the growth of the usage of your web application, you might have a connection leak. If you confirm that, you would have to investigate that leak.

Unlike the "olden days", if you connect to the datavase via Hibernate and manage transactions with, say, Spring, connection leaks are quite rare.